# How to process events in FIFO order?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, concurrency

I'm writing a program which maintains a state in the State object. Every time the state changes, a new thread in this program is created and a callback function is called on that thread and the new state is passed as a parameter to this function. This function is called `OnStateChange`.

For this question, I'm only concerned with 2 states: `State1`, `State2`. Following are the semantics associated with the 2 states:

1. State1: If state has been changed to `State1`, check if this state persists for 80 seconds. If state persisted for 80 seconds, call `DoWorkForState1(...)` else if the state did not persist (another state change event occurred within 80 seconds), discard the `DoWorkForState1(...)`. If a change to `State1` is queued while a thread is already waiting for 80 seconds, drop this new event for `State1` and let the existing thread do the work.
2. State2: This should make threads processing `State1` and waiting for 80 seconds, to not call `DoWorkForState1(...)`. `DoWorkForState2(...)` should be called now.

The solution I worked on but soon, I realized it can fail:

```
Event StateTransition;                // Event that is set when a state change occurs
Boolean IsAThreadWaitingOnState1;     
Function OnStateChange(NewState)      // Callback invoked a new thread every time StateTransition occurs
{
    Lock();                           // Protect the write to the State variable in a lock
    State = NewState;
    Unlock();
    if (NewState == State2)
    {
        SetEvent(StateTransition);    // Let threads waiting for 80 seconds on State1 know, state has changed to State2
        DoWorkForState2();
    }
    else if (NewState == State1)
    {
        Lock();
        if (IsAThreadWaitingOnState1 == true)
        {
            Unlock();
            return;                                                       // Drop this State1 since a thread is already waiting for 80 seconds
        }
        IsAThreadWaitingOnState1 = true;
        Unlock();
        Result = WaitOnEvent(Event = StateTransition, Time = 80 seconds);  // Assume an API that lets you wait on an event for a specified time
        ResetEvent(StateTransition)
        if (Result == Timeout)                                             // If State1 persits, Do work for this state
        {
            DoWorkForState1();
        }

    }
}
```

The above solution would work correctly if the callback above processes state changes in the order they were generated but the lock in function does not ensure that.

For e.g., if the state transitions are: State1, State2, State1 and the respective callbacks run on threads T1, T2, T3.

The required outcome should have been that first State1 would for wait for 80 seconds, State2 arrives within 80 seconds and dequeues the previous State1. The next State1 waits for 80 seconds and runs since no state change follows.

If the scheduler runs thread as T1, T3, T2, the outcome will be first State1 arrives and waits for 80 seconds, the second State1 arrives and is dropped (since T1 is waiting already), State2 arrives within 80 seconds and dequeues the first State1 as well. This outcomes is clearly different.

There are other problems as well. Can anyone suggest a good solution to this problem?

Comment: Starting a new thread to handle an event is seldom a good design. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I should have rephrased it more appropriately. I'm looking at an existing piece of code. It involves a process that can send notifications to the interested clients through events. Every interested client registers a callback that will be invoked whenever an event is generated. I wrote a pseudo code above to solve a part of my problem. But in the second half, I mention that my solution will fail if events are not processed in FIFO order and there is no way to guarantee that. Where can I read about design patterns that can solve problems similar to mine above?

Comment: If you need things processed in FIFO order, what are the threads doing - just waiting for the predecessor to complete? So there is no real concurrency anyway. You can have a single callback-processing thread and an event queue, and it is automatically FIFO.